# RESTful GET and GET(all) URLs in web.py

Tags: python, web.py

in web.py, how do I specify URLs for GET(all) and GET/id?

Here's what I have. My intent is that the GET without argument is called when there is no argument. This would correspond to getting a listing of all the data for my_url.  If an id were supplied, I'd hope the other method would be called, and that it would use the argument to return one row.

Clearly, it does not work this way.

Do I need to simply declare a new class for 'get all' case?

```
urls= (
    '/my_url/(.+)', 'my_class',
    '/my_url', 'my_class'
)

class my_class:
    def GET(self):
        return "..."
    def GET(self, id):
        return "... {0}".format(id)
```

Comment: at a guess you come from c++ landia

Comment: @JoranBeasley Java. But I am schizophrenic. I suppose I have my case/underscores askew from the standard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python you use default values for arguments that may not be present

```
class my_class:
    def GET(self,id=None):
        if id is None:
            return "..."
        else:
            return "other..."
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Now I have more to research!  I'll accept in 7 more minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
'/my_url(?:$|/(.+))', 'my_class',
```

where '?:' means ignoring the outer group, while group (.+) remains
may this help.